# Python typeerror 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, matrix, rotation

so I have a program in python where I have some points and on a key press I need to have them rotate along and axis so press x it will rotate around the x axis press y for y and z for z.

I am pretty sure I have the code layed out correctly 
first I define my rotation values

```
x_rot = 1
y_rot = 1
z_rot = 1
```

Next I setup my math values:

```
   #setup angles for rotation
angle = 1
rad = angle * math.pi / 180
cose = math.cos(rad)
sine = math.sin(rad)
```

I then set up my points my x y and z points in lists called Xs, Ys, and Zs in the following format:

```
   Xs=(12.0, 25.0, 10.0, 22.0)
   Ys=(2.0, 15.0, 12.0, 27.0) 
   Zs=(21.0, 23.0, 1.0, 12.0)
```

Next I setup my key presses to multiply my coordinate values by a rotation matrix so my points rotate around the x axis when I push the x button on my keyboard.

```
done = False

while done == False:
    # ALL EVENT PROCESSING SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
            # User pressed down on a key

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN | event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                y_rot == Ys*cose(angle)-Zs*(angle)
                z_rot == Ys*sine(angle)-Zs*cose(angle)
                x_rot == Xs
```

I then run my code and it works fine until I press the x button to rotate it.  when I press the button I get an error saying

```
typeerror 'float' object is not callable
```

and it references this line

```
y_rot == Ys*cose(angle)-Zs*(angle)
```

I have a feeling that this is a simple fix but I just can not think of what it might be.

Comment: And what do you expect `cose(angle)` to *do*? Multiply?

Comment: i want to take the cosine of the angle which is 1 in this case and then multiply it by my value

Comment: As a side note: Since you've tagged this `matrix`, and you seem to be having problems understanding how to apply a calculation to all of the elements of a tuple, I have a feeling that [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org) might change your life.

Comment: Also, see [`math.radians`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.radians) for an easier way to convert degrees to radians. (Not that you're having a problem with that part, but I think it's still more readable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assigned a float value to `cose`:

```
cose = math.cos(rad)
```

and then try to use that value as a function with `cose(angle)`:

```
y_rot == Ys*cose(angle)-Zs*(angle)
```

There is more wrong with that line, but lets focus on the `cose(angle)` first. If you meant to use that as a multiplication, do so:

```
Ys * cose * angle - Zs * angle
```

The parenthesis only serve to confuse here; use them only when you need to group expressions.

Note that `==` is a test for equality; if you wanted to **assign** then use single `=` equals:

```
y_rot = Ys * cose * angle - Zs * angle
z_rot = Ys * sine * angle - Zs * cose * angle
x_rot = Xs
```

If `Ys` and `Zs` are *tuples*, you need to apply this to each element of the tuples separately:

```
y_rot = tuple(y * cose * angle - z * angle for y, z in zip(Ys, Zs))
z_rot = tuple(y * sine * angle - z * cose * angle for y, z in zip(Ys, Zs))
x_rot = Xs
```

which for your stated values of `Ys`, `Zs` gives:

```
>>> tuple(y * cose * angle - z * angle for y, z in zip(Ys, Zs))
(-19.000304609687216, -8.002284572654132, 10.998172341876696, 14.995887769222563)
>>> tuple(y * sine * angle - z * cose * angle for y, z in zip(Ys, Zs))
(-20.96189678540965, -22.734710892037747, -0.7904188179089892, -11.526957368070041)
```

I am not too familiar with how you'd calculate the rotation matrix here; I've paired the `Ys` and `Zs` tuple elements up for each calculation; but I suspect the calculation is more involved. The point is more that you cannot just multiply a float with a tuple and hope that the right calculations materialize.

Comment: first thank you for your help this help me understand my mistakes.  i needed to do y_rot = (Ys*cose)-(Zs*-sine).  This fixed my issue

Comment: now when i run it i get an error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float.  i think it is because i am multiplying a float (cose) by a tuple (Ys).  Is there a way i can do this multiplication?

Comment: @craft3maker: You'll have to do this for each element *in* the tuple: `y_rot = tuple(i * cose * angle - Zs * angle for i in Ys)`.

Comment: One minor nit: I might avoid using the names `i` and `j` here, just because they may lead the reader into thinking we're doing complex math here. (An experienced Python user would know that you'd have to write `1j` or the like to do that, but a novice could easily be misled.)

Comment: @abarnert: what would you use here?

Comment: Since you're iterating over `zip(Ys, Zs)`, why not `y, z`?

Comment: @abarnert: much better idea, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined `cose`, it immediately calculates the value of `math.cos(rad)` and assigns the float result to `cose`.  Then later you try to call `cose(angle)`, which basically is the same as calling `2.7(angle)`, i.e. it's nonsense.

I think you want something more like this:

```
def cose(angle):
    angle = 0
    rad = angle * math.pi / 180
    return math.cos(rad)

def sine(angle):
    angle = 0
    rad = angle * math.pi / 180
    return math.sin(rad)
```

I'd be surprised if this degree/radian conversion isn't already built into Python, though.

Answer (score 0):

The way you coded that part it's saying that `cose` is a function with an argument `angle`

```
cose(angle) 


y_rot == Ys*cose*(angle)-Zs*(angle)
                ^
                |
            Maybe you are missing this.
```